# Titanium - Android: Intent - getData(), getAction() always equal to null

Tags: javascript, android, titanium-mobile, deep-linking, appcelerator-titanium

When I use the deep link for my project and try to access the `Ti.Android.currentActivity.getIntent().getData()` it always returns `null` for `Ti SDK 6.2.0` and above but If I downgrade the SDK to 6.1.2 then it works fine. It cannot read data from incoming intents.

Steps to Reproduce:

1. Create a new alloy App and use the following test code
2. Install the app on any android device.
3. Goto the browser and browse to link `app name://videoURL`
4. It will open up the app but `getData()` is always null but it should return a URL

Expected Result: It should return the URL when the App is opened from the deep link.

Here is the test code:

In alloy.js:

```
Alloy.Globals.getDeepLinkURL = function() {
    Alloy.Globals.deepLinkURLAndroid =Ti.Android.currentActivity.getIntent().getData();

    console.log("Alloy.Globals.deepLinkURLAndroid");
    console.log(Alloy.Globals.deepLinkURLAndroid);
    console.log(Ti.Android.currentActivity.getIntent());
};
```

In index.js:

```
$.index.addEventListener('open',function(){
    if(OS_ANDROID){
        Alloy.Globals.getDeepLinkURL();
    }

});
```

Comment: It looks like you forgot to add the test code to reproduce.

Comment: Hi Haem thanks for the reply. I have added the test code.

Answer (score 0):

```
Ti.Android.currentActivity.addEventListener('newintent', function (e) {
    var data = e.intent.getData();
    alert(`data: ${data}`);
});
```

Which returns the data but this code only works in index.js file